# How do you uses nested elements in a force directed D3 graph?

Tags: d3.js

I had a look at Mike Bostocks lesson on nested elements here:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

It's logical to use element nesting, but for some reason I cannot find any examples of nesting in force directed graphs. For example, why not nest text elements inside nodes so if you hover over a node, text will appear in response to the hover event.  Without nesting you'd have to come up with some kind of mechanism to match the text element to the node element. Indeed, I see all kinds of strange variations of methods to do this rather then using nesting.

In short, can anyone provide an example of a force directed graph that uses nested elements?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that a "node" is a completely abstract concept. You can use any kind of element, or whole groups of elements to represent a node.

One thing you might try is using `g` elements to represent your nodes, and using a translation to position them on each tick.

That way, upon a node entering, you can append any number of elements to it, and they will remain attached to that node. For example, you could attach a circle element and a text element, and then both elements will follow their parent `g` element around while the force layout is running.

Then you can simply use css to achieve the hover effect you want. For example, assuming you had `g` elements for nodes, each having a class of `.node`, you could show/hide the text upon hovering as follows:

```
.node text {
  opacity: 0;
}
.node:hover text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/roboke/2/edit?css,js,output) is a very simple example you can follow to achieve the kind of labeled nodes that I think you are after, using the technique I described. Hope that helps.

Comment: I suspect there might be a good reason why nested text is not used in many of these force directed graph examples. I've tweaked your example a bit [HERE](http://jsbin.com/xajalo/7/). If you hover over the labels, you can see that other nodes end up obscuring the text.  Perhaps it's possible to solve this problem using z-index attributes?

Comment: Found yet another problematic element of this nesting approach.  Problematic not in the sense that its wrong, but that it should be used with caution and may explain the lack of examples.  In the augmented example above, the hover event is now triggered in what appears to be space between the nodes rather than the node itself, since the large labels have now become part of the g element that triggers the hover event.

Comment: You don't have to nest in that case. Remember the important point: *a node is an abstraction*, it's just data; just a set of coordinates. You can bind that data to multiple elements. [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/bazalu/1/edit?css,js,output) is a different approach. I've created two separate layers for the nodes and the labels. Then data is bound to both circles *and* labels, and the hover interaction is done by matching the index of the hovered circle to the label with that same index. Finally, in the css, I've turned off pointer events for the label layer so that it doesn't interfere.

Comment: One final thing you might try, if you're interested. You can trigger the label on the *nearest* circle to the cursor using a transparent voronoi geometry as I've done [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/bazalu/2/edit?css,js,output). Try changing the stroke color of `.polygon` in the css if you want to see the shapes. It makes for a nice, fluid mouseover experience, and further reinforces the idea that force layout nodes can be represented by anything, even voronoi polygons.

Comment: Hi, I used your examples to implement a graph that works perfectly the way I had envisioned, you can see it here, although it's still a work in progress.  http://ives.herokuapp.com/graph  Mouse over the nodes to see text etc. I'll try to implement your final suggestion later today, but it has all been extremely helpful so far.. understanding the internals is key when working with D3 and I'm slowly getting there.